# C program to change MAC address of a network Adapter

Tags: c, visual-c++, network-programming, ip-address

I know of C API GetAdaptersAddresses() where by we can extracts the MAC no of a computer and prints it using Iphlpapi.lib - but how can we Set the MAC address using C API?

The adapter that I am talking is Loopback Adapter

```
GetAdaptersAddresses(0, 0, NULL, adapter, &len);
MACaddress(adapter->Address);

static void MACaddress( .. .... )
{
     ................................
    printf("MAC Address: %02X-%02X-%02X-%02X-%02X-%02X\n",
    d[0], d[1], d[2], d[3], d[4], d[5]);
}
```

Comment: Are we suppose to be able to change MAC?

Comment: I am not sure but can we not change the MAC for a Loopback Adapter?

Comment: There is no Win32 API to change the MAC address. This is done by editing Registry. Maybe these days they have a powershell applet as well.

Comment: Please let me C code implementation to change the Registry value - find and update the same. Also hints of powershell applet would be an added advantage